# Javascript block within partial not executed after partial gets rendered -- Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

When rendering partials, are Javascript blocks within a partial supposed to get executed?

For instance, assume inside "_partial_exmaple.html.erb" is a call to alert().

When I render this partial inside a view, will this alert get invoked?

If so, I'm doing something wrong as the Javascript blocks contained inside a partial are not getting executed.

Inside "viewA.html.erb":

```
<%= render :partial => 'partialA' %>
```

Inside "_partialA.html.erb":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('hi');
</script>
```

The alert function to display "hi" is not getting executed.

Comment: What do you mean by "javascript blocks" exactly? What code isn't working for you?

Comment: Could you provide an example? A partial just contributes to the resulting HTML, so if the `alert()` is within a `<script>` block, it should be executed.

Comment: Yes, let me update the post with more concrete code. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: If that script is output to the page at all, it will get invoked. View the source of your page from your browser and copy/paste the results in here.

Comment: I should also add that I'm using Colorbox, the jQuery lightbox. Maybe I can post the code somewhere.

Comment: To be precise, the results of the partial are rendered in a jQuery Colorbox as an overlay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have a JavaScript error somewhere before this line of code, which is halting all JavaScript execution.  Use your browser's JavaScript console to check for any errors.

In Chrome: View -> Developer -> JavaScript Console

Comment: You are a smart man. Ever since Firebug changed its error count behavior, we miss more and more little errors. Often times, it'll display the error for a split second then the error count will vanish from the Firebug button. The only way to know an error occurred is to check the Console manually. Argh. Thanks!